# Transaction Too Large Exception with rememberLauncherForActivityResult

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen which shows LazyVerticalGrid with Pictures and TopBar with OnClick that creates new activity for result to choose a Directory for pictures to show

```
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun DisplayPictures(
    pictures: List<Uri>,
    navController: NavController,
    appBarName: String = stringResource(id = R.string.choose_folder),
    onNewDirectoryUri: (uri: Uri?) -> Unit = { }
) {
    var showDirectorySelect by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (showDirectorySelect) {
        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(),
            onResult = {
                onNewDirectoryUri(it)
                showDirectorySelect = false
            })
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            launcher.launch(null)
        }
    }
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = {
            Text(
                text = appBarName.dropLastWhile { predicate -> predicate == '%' },
                Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )
        }, Modifier.clickable { showDirectorySelect = true })
    })
    {
        if (!showDirectorySelect) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                maxColumnWidth = 150.dp,
                paddingDp = 4.dp,
                pictures = pictures
            ) { uri ->
                val route = Screen.Detail.createRoute(
                    URLEncoder.encode(
                        uri.toString(),
                        "UTF-8"
                    )
                )
                //Prevent multi-clicking and multi-touch
                if (!navController.currentDestination?.route?.contains("detail")!!) {
                    navController.navigate(route)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason my app crashes with TransactionTooLargeException after user chose directory or just closed the app to background(clicked home button for example). I guess the problem is in LazyVerticalGrid(Its another composable function which is just lazy column with rows) which contains Pictures. So Picture is Composable function which loads Image from URI

```
//A wrapper around Image that shows placeholder and loading image via URI
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun Picture(
    uri: Uri,
    modifier: Modifier,
    size: Size,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    val bitmap: MutableState<Bitmap?> = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(null) }
    //Coil and other libraries that can get image from uri get context this way
    val context = LocalContext.current
    bitmap.value ?: run {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    bitmap.value = context.contentResolver.loadThumbnail(uri, size, null)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .placeholder(visible = bitmap.value == null)

    ) {
        bitmap.value?.let {
            Log.i("longgg",uri.toString())
            Image(
                bitmap = it.asImageBitmap(),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(RectangleShape)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .clickable { onClick() }
            )
        }
    }
```

As I researched the whole Compose function DisplayPictures does recompose and LazyGrid download all pictures again after ActivityResultContract. This results to load a lot of thumbnails and I get a TransactionTooLargeException. The onNewDirectoryUri creates new mvi Event which starts DisplayPictures but with new params(new pictures and etc). How can I fix this behavior?

I found out that loadThumbnail method creates bundle under the hood

```
final Bundle opts = new Bundle();
opts.putParcelable(EXTRA_SIZE, new Point(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight()));
```

Answer (score 0):

TransactionTooLargeException occurs when the data being passed among two activities is too large I think the bundle has limitations on how much data it can carry. Check what result you are sending through bundles.

Try to avoid sending bitmaps instead just send the URL of the image and reload the same in your activity.

Comment: The only thing i pass through bundle is URI of directory user chose. I pass only URI to image, it gets thumbnail(Bitmap) inside the function

Comment: Then Check at how many Uri selection this breaks if it is breaking in 3 - 4 Uri then definitely there is some data in Bundle that is causing this crash.